# Reading excel to a python data frame starting from row 5 & column 5 and including headers as well?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The excel workbook i've is already formated and start from the row 6 & column 5.
So when i'm importing its shows nan values in the initiall rows and columns.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | First Name | Last Name | Age |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Summit | Kumar | 32 |

```
target_hcp = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Downloads\\EMD Data\Target List\HCP List.csv", skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
target_hcp.head()
```

I've tried skiprows which helped me to read so the rows problem is handled. But columns issue is still there. How to handle this?

```
target_hcp = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Downloads\\EMD Data\Target List\HCP List.csv", skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: read all without skipping any rows, just dropna later

Answer (score 0):

You can use Usecols() while reading the file, you can specify the column names in it or indexing of column

```
target_hcp = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Downloads\\EMD Data\Target List\HCPList.csv", skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5], usecols = ["Column E", "Column F", "Column G"])
```

specify the column name or indexing in the list of usecols option.

or you can drop first five columns after reading the file.

```
target_hcp = target_hcp.drop(columns=['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'], inplace=True)
```